# RecyclerView Error No adapter attached ; skipping layout and setting OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm working on an application where I store the data on Firebase and retrieve it after the user manages to sign in. The application works fine I see this error occurs.

E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

I'm loading an image together with long and short description. I'm trying to take the users into another Activity where they can the content more detailed. However. I am confused where I can set  OnClickListener so that I can take the id of this post and load it in another activity.

this is the main activity :

```java
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        homeAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true); // this will load it from the end and show last as first

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        postModelList = new ArrayList<>();

        pullPosts();



    }
```

and this is the method where I pull the data from the DB :

```java
 void pullPosts() {
         progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait for the pictures to load...");
         progressDialog.show();
         progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postModelList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    postModel = ds.getValue(PostModel.class);
                    postModelList.add(postModel);
                    postAdapter = new PostAdapter(HomeActivity.this , postModelList);

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, ""+databaseError, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

I read other posts related to that error tried the options but the rest seems to me fine as the following is my Adapter :

```java
public class PostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostAdapter.MyHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<PostModel> postModelList;

    public PostAdapter(Context context, List<PostModel> postModelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.postModelList = postModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.home_post, parent, false);


        return new MyHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {

        String title = postModelList.get(position).getPostTitle();
        String sDescription = postModelList.get(position).getPostShDescription();
        String lDescription = postModelList.get(position).getPostLoDescription();
        String image = postModelList.get(position).getPostImage();

        holder.pulledTitle.setText(title);
        holder.pulledShortDescription.setText(sDescription);
        holder.pulledLongDescription.setText(lDescription);
        Glide.with(context).load(image).into(holder.pulledImage);
        //now we will add library to load image
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postModelList.size();
    }

    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        ImageView pulledImage;
        TextView pulledTitle, pulledShortDescription, pulledLongDescription;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            pulledImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pulled_image);
            pulledTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pulled_title);
            pulledShortDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pulled_short_description);
            pulledLongDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pulled_long_description);
        }


    }
}
```

Could you please help me with fixing the issue? I would appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

that's not an error you can ignore it, it's happening because there's not adapter when the activity is created as you set the adapter after fetching the data.
About your question where to set onClickListener, you should do that in the adapter's viewHolder

```
class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

   

     ImageView pulledImage;
        TextView pulledTitle, pulledShortDescription, pulledLongDescription;
    
        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
    
            pulledImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pulled_image);
            pulledTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pulled_title);
            pulledShortDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pulled_short_description);
            pulledLongDescription =         itemView.findViewById(R.id.pulled_long_description);

            itemView.setOnClickListner(v->{
       //your implementation here  f.e Id = postModelList.getId(); or and start another activity from here
});
        }
    
    
    }
```